# Export from Access to Excel limitation

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I need to export 351 196 rows from Access to Excel and it allows to export not more than 65000 at a time. Is there any code which will allow to export necessary number of rows at one time?

Thank you!

Comment: Upgrade to Excel 2007 or later. You can have over 1M rows per spreadsheet. Excel 2003 and earlier limits it to 65k rows per sheet. An alternative is to divide your data into multiple sheets.

Comment: I have Microsoft office professional plus 2013. IS there any code to devide my rows into 6 sheets? (except of Select - DELETE -SELECT -DELETE and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

65K is the limit with formatting. Export without formatting.